Looking for minimum and maximum elevation for US counties
Where can I find minimum and maximum elevation data for US counties?
It would be a bonus if I could directly access it from within R, but other solutions are also good.

If all else fails, would it work for you to have a DEM and a shapefile with county borders, such that you can calculate it yourself?

That would be possible.

Use {geodata} package for elevation and boundaries, then use terra::zonal or terra::extract to get the min/max values, like:
elev <- geodata::elevation_30s("USA", path = "data")
usa <- geodata::gadm("USA", path = "data")

usa$NAME_1 |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  dplyr::mutate(max = terra::zonal(elev, usa, fun = "max", na.rm = TRUE))
#>              usa$NAME_1 USA_elv_msk
#> 1               Alabama         689
#> 2                Alaska         NaN
#> 3               Arizona        3709
[...]
#> 51              Wyoming        4032

There are missing values for Alaska and Hawaii because USA in elevation_30s data set is filtered to mainland:
terra::plot(elev)


You can use geodata::elevation_global() to get global coverage and extract data.
Created on 2024-08-28 with reprex v2.1.0

Nice, thanks! Good to know about geodata and this approach.
